# What happened to the helium 3 tanks of america in movie Iron-Sky?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, iron-sky

At the end all nations were fighting with each other. America was fighting to save its helium 3 tanks on moon. Were they saved or destroyed?

Comment: Weren't they German helium-3 tanks?

Comment: No they were the americans , in last american president accepted that...

Comment: @NIleshSharma No, they were not American but Moon-German. The president just claimed them after the Nazis were defeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

America claims the tanks so it would become independent of other nations (on the helium 3 front). All nations then begin to fight over the claim, making them turn on each other. It is not shown if the tank survive or not, only the burning wreckage of the nazi base is visibly shown.